# cURL: Java website not loading

Tags: networking, curl, http

I can access the configuration page of my device with no problems via web browser (on the GUI).
But it doesn't seem to work by using cURL:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ curl http://192.168.1.232
<html><head>
<script src="jsMain.js"> </script>
<title>DWL-2100AP</title></head>

<script language='JavaScript'>
document.cookie = 'RpWebID=57562c4e';
</script>
<script language='JavaScript'>
function JumpToHmain(){location.replace('/html/HomeWizard.html');}window.setTimeout('JumpToHmain()',1);</script>
```

Same results by accepting cookies:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ curl http://192.168.1.232 -c cookie.txt
<html><head>
<script src="jsMain.js"> </script>
<title>DWL-2100AP</title></head>

<script language='JavaScript'>
document.cookie = 'RpWebID=57562c5c';
</script>
<script language='JavaScript'>
function JumpToHmain(){location.replace('/html/HomeWizard.html');}window.setTimeout('JumpToHmain()',1);</script>
```

But if I try to go to that initial `/html/HomeWizard.html` configuration page (this time I try sending username and password, as long as I assume it will be needed):

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Authorization:Basic admin:MyEditedPassword' http://192.168.1.232/html/HomeWizard.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.06
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
<title>Object Not Found</title></head><body>
<h1>Object Not Found</h1>The requested URL '/html/HomeWizard.html' was not found on the RomPager server.<p>Return to <A HREF="">last page</A><p>
```

Test without the `Accept/application/json` part:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ curl -i -H 'Authorization:Basic admin:MyEditedPassword' http://192.168.1.232/html/HomeWizard.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.06
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
<title>Object Not Found</title></head><body>
<h1>Object Not Found</h1>The requested URL '/html/HomeWizard.html' was not found on the RomPager server.<p>Return to <A HREF="">last page</A><p>
</body></html>
```

No problem at all accessing the GUI by navigating to `http://192.168.1.232/html/HomeWizard.html` via Firefox (after entering credentials, of course).

What is going on here and how could I solve it?

Further data:

- The website uses Java, or so I think.

Comment: I do not believe that the router will understand `-H 'Accept:application/json'`.  That is certainly **not** something a browser doing HTTP authentication would send.  I'm confident you need to talk `text/html` with it.

Comment: @grochmal , tested without `-H 'Accept:application/json'` . Updated original post. Same results.

Comment: You should put a space after the `:` in your header. Also for `Basic` auth, the credentials need to be base64 encoded, your example isn't. Also the `-c` option tells curl to store cookies. If you want curl to send the cookies back you also need `-b`. Also try your original ("GET /") request with `-L`, which will tell curl to follow any redirect headers (assuming there is one).